# Remove all 10s in a list and append a same number of 0s to the list at the end in JAVA

Tags: java

I've done most part of this. Anyone give me a small hint about how do I find the number of 10s in the list. 
Eg. Input would be

> [10,4,6,10,6,7]

Output must be

> [4,6,6,7,0,0]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class prob64 {
   public static List output;
   public static void getVal(List ll)
   {
       int count=0;
       List ll1=new ArrayList();
       for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++)
       {
           if((int)ll.get(i)!=10)
           {
               ll1.add(ll.get(i));
           }
           if((int)ll.get(i)==10)
           {
               count++;
           }
       }
       if(count>0)
       {
          ll1.add(8);
       }   
       output=ll1;
       System.out.println(output);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ll=new ArrayList();
        ll.add(10);
        ll.add(1);
        ll.add(10);
        ll.add(2);
        prob64.getVal(ll);
   }
}
```

The current output I'm getting is `[1,2,0]`. I'm supposed to get `[1,2,0,0]`

Comment: Start by indenting your code properly, to make it readable. And use generic lists (List<Integer>) instead of raw lists (List). Then choose other names than `ll` and `ll1`, which really look like you obfuscated your code on purpose to make it unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

`List.remove(Object)` removes the first matching element. It also returns a boolean indicating if a removal was really done, so this should work :

```
while(ll.remove(10)) {
  ll.add(0);
}
```

That is, as long as you find 10s to remove, add 0s. Note that `List.add` adds the element at the end of the list, which is your requirement (if I'm correct).

I suppose this is some kind of learning exercise, but I would advise you to find better names for your variable (`ll` & `ll1` does not make your function easy to read).

Answer (score 2):

You are adding only one zero at the end of the loop (in case *10s* were found). You should count the number of *10s* then *add zeros as much as this number*. Your program should look something like this:

```
int count=0;
List ll1=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++)
{
    if((int)ll.get(i)!=10)
       ll1.add(ll.get(i));
    else
       count++;
}

for(int j=0; j<count;j++)
    ll1.add(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `count` is number of 10's to add, use:

```
for(int j=0; j<count;j++){
    ll1.add(8); // or ll1.add(0); ???
}
```

Comment: Oh..just been missing this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Few points to add to what others have mentioned above

1. I don't see any reason why you must define the output List to be **static**. When you define something(variables/functions) as static they are owned by the class rather that the objects and also it is a good programming practice not to change them using instance functions.What I mean is if you wish only to print there is no need of that output instance variable. You can directly print ll1.
2. Please use Generics in your code. When you know all you have in your list are integers specify it - Even in the function **getVal**(). I don't know how your code is compiling but you **cannot cast Object to an int**.

   ```
   (int)ll.get(i)!=10
   ```

   This code will fail. Try using **Integer** instead of int.
3. Your problem statement read replacing all 10's with 0's. So why are you adding 8 instead.It must be

   ```
   ll1.add(0);
   ```

   As other have specifies you need to add 0 as many time as your count is. So another loop is needed. Rest all look good.